# Scheduling backup for Azure App Service - Function Apps when hosted on app service plan on Standard tier

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

we were able to schedule backups and monitor them for web apps hosted on Azure app service plan (Standard tier). we were also able to configure backups for function apps hosted on app service plans. but the backups are not happening as in web apps.

Could you please help on this. Is the feature supported with function apps. If not supported why are we able to configure backups for function apps also.

Update 1: Joy, thanks for confirmation.
 [providing you the error shown in log while backup, any clue for figuring it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnA00.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try again, I test it on my side, it works fine. Refer to my screenshots.

My azure function in a **Standard** service plan:

[image]

Backup configured, `scheduled backup started on Thursday, July 12, 2018, 1:30:15 PM GMT+8`. And it succeeded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy for confirmation. I will remove existing setup and try setting it up again.

Comment: @3218801 The error happens now? Could you provide the configure steps? Or could you create a new function app to try again?

Comment: @3218801 Did you access it via `Platform features`->`Backups`?

Comment: yes accessed it via all settings -> backups. then created new container in storage account and mapped it through "configure" option in backups.

Comment: @3218801 Where to find the error message screenshot you post? If you create a new function app, could you set backup successfully?

Comment: hey it worked with new function app. the issue seem to be with function apps originally created with consumption plan but migrated to app service plan later. any thoughts on how this could be limiting backup configurations..?

Comment: the function app was created in consumption plan but now moved to app service plan. for function apps in consumption plan, backup configurations are not available.

Comment: @3218801 Yes, but the content is stored in a file share, refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60d1f1ff-09d5-4d54-a3ea-c9f14465373b/is-there-any-way-to-backup-an-azure-function).

Comment: Thanks Joy, that helps. Marking my question as answered.

Comment: @3218801 Glad to help you.